# Snap wont install latest version of Thunderbird

Tags: 20.04, snap, thunderbird

I upgraded my 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS a couple of days ago and ran all updates possible. So now I need encrypted PGP Mail and wanted to install the latest Thunderbird 78.x. Current installation was 68.x.

I followed the suggestions available on SE and the internet, but to no avail. Here is what I tried:

First try:

1. Remove Thunderbird per terminal: `sudo apt remove thunderbird`
2. Install snap Version of thunderbird: `sudo snap install thunderbird`

Result: Another Thunderbird of 68.x

Second try:

1. Remove Snap's Thunderbird: `sudo snap remove thunderbird`
2. Install "beta" of thunderbird: `sudo snap install thunderbird --beta` (I hoped this would offer me a cutting edge or something of Thunderbird.)

Result: Terminal says "Kanal latest/beta für thunderbird ist geschlossen; leite zeitweise an stable weiter." (Translation: "Channel latest/beta for thunderbird is closed; diverting to stable temporarily"). Another Thunderbird 68.x

The snap Website tells, that I could install it via "Ubuntu Software". I opened it and the Drop-Down menu on the top right is set to latest/stable. But again only 68.x available.

On the snap website I looked for further information, but it says I only have to run the 2nd command of the 2nd try, which I did, as you may have read. Another Thread here on askUbuntu says: "Simply wait for integration". Sorry, but this is not a solution.

What am I gonna do now? Has anyone got a solution? This is pretty annoying, because I don't want to go the manual way, because of updates and so on. Is something broken on my system?

**EDIT (as requested from comment):**
As requested from comment, I list the output:

```
➜ snap list thunderbird        
Name         Version  Rev  Aufzeichnung   Herausgeber  Hinweise
thunderbird  78.3.3   90   latest/stable  canonical✓   -
```

Fascinating. When hitting "Super"-key, writing `thunder*` and hitting Enter-key, then the old 68.x opens (to be seen  via Help --> About Thunderbird).

I double-checked whether the classic apt kept another version (`sudo apt remove thunderbird`, result: Cannot be found, therefore cannot be uninstalled.)

**EDIT 2 (as requested from comment):**
After running `whereis thunderbird` this is the output:

```
➜ whereis thunderbird
  thunderbird: /etc/thunderbird /snap/bin/thunderbird
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1286172/edit) to show us the complete output of `snap list thunderbird`

Comment: @user535733 Done.

Comment: Okay, that one is version 78. Next, look at the output of `whereis thunderbird`.  It will show multiple results. You are looking for a result that is not provided by the Snap.  There might be one, there might not.

Comment: @user535733 Done2.

Comment: @user535733 you won't believe it. I rebooted the stupid crap of a computer and behold: TB 78.3.3 will start, when opening it via the "Super"-key menu. I don't know why, but though I removed the old stuff completely and installed the snapped version, it still used somehow old data, that was already removed from the system. I would really appreciate, if you could answer me, how a non resident program can access old files, that were removed with apt remove command...

Comment: Well, glad you got it solved. I won't speculate. It's amazing how many mysterious problems a reboot solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I simply rebooted the computer**. Then Thunderbird 78.3.3 loaded from the GNOME menu like it should.

Answer (score 3):

If you're having this issue simply do the following:

Purge the old apt package of Thunderbird:

```
sudo apt purge thunderbird
```

Install the new snap package of Thunderbird:

```
sudo snap install thunderbird
```

Rebooting may or may not be neccessary.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: If I install the snap version of Thunderbird 92.3.2 I am unable to get beyond the "Confirm Security Exception" button when I try to read main from my own server. (I am able to do so on the apt version 78.14.0 and on the Windows 92.3.1. Seems to be a known issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1904789